# Magento display multiple discounts in cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am currently looking for a way to display multiple discounts in the Magento shopping cart without having to buy an extension.  If a customer is purchasing an order over $50 then shipping is free, if they use coupon code "rush13" then they get a 10% discount.  The shipping price and discount are both calculating correctly but they are showing up on one line.  Is there a way display the discounts broken down?  I feel this would be easier on the customer to see how much they are receiving for each discount.

I'm using Magento 1.7

#### --Current Display--

Subtotal: $xxx.xx

Discount (Free Shipping, Applied Coupon Code RUSH13) -$xx.xx

#### --Preferred Display--

Subtotal: $xxx.xx

Discount(Free Shipping) -$xx.xx

Discount(Coupon Code RUSH13) -$xx.xx

#### --This Could Also Work --

Subtotal: $xxx.xx

Discount(Free Shipping -$xx.xx, Coupon Code RUSH13 -$xx.xx) -$xx.xx

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't like posting questions without code here but I'm not sure where to start on this one.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

class `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` is  responsible for discount calculation. So we can set our Discount Description from this looped calculation.

in the method

`public function process(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item)`

look for the code

`$discountAmount = $result->getDiscountAmount();`

and place these 2 lines after above code which will prepare our description array in current foreach loop

```
$_formatedDiscountAmount = Mage::helper('core')->currency($discountAmount, true, false);
$_descriptionArray[] = $rule->getName()."-".$_formatedDiscountAmount;
```

and at last, right after the end of the foreach place this code

```
$address->setDiscountDescriptionArray($_descriptionArray);
```

Comment: Discount amount does not seem to be correct when there is two or more item in the cart, any idea？